# InlineCreate Operation does not work for HasMany relationship in Laravel backpack 5

Tags: laravel-backpack-5

I can't use InlineCreate Operation for the case of HasMany relationship in laravel backpack 5.

I've a page for creating new item group which will allow to add multiple attributes and multiple attribute values for each corresponding attribute.

`ItemGroup` model has following function

```
public function attributes(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
}
```

`Attribute` model has following function

```
public function attributeValues(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
}
```

Item group creation page: https://i.postimg.cc/zfdV7JhB/Screen-Shot-2023-03-06-at-1-47-20-PM.png

In ItemGroupCrudController, I tried to add the following code block to achieve inline creation of Attribute values. But this did nothing.

```
use InlineCreateOperation;
...
...

protected function setupCreateOperation(): void
{
...

$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'attributes',
    'type' => "relationship",
        'subfields' => [
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => "Attribute",
                'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6']
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'attributeValues',
                'label'    => "Values",
                'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6']

                'type' => "relationship",
                'ajax' => true,
                'inline_create' => true,
            ]
        ],
]);
```

The reason I guess inline create operation does not work for HasMany relation.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... difficult to know when there is no error message. But two things stand out to me:

(1) `'inline_create' => true` only works for single relationships (1-1, 1-n). For multiple relationships (n-n) you have to define the entity. Take a look at Step 2 in the docs of InlineCreate - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-inline-create#how-to-use. In your case I believe it would be:

```
                'inline_create' => ['entity' => 'attributeValue'],
```

(2) Please make sure there is a CRUD for `attributeValues`. That is what InlineCreate does, it takes the Create screen from that CRUD... and uses it inside another CRUD.